# Custom uitableview cell not showing all text labels

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show an object from firebase in a custom cell. It  has three text labels. When, I run my code it only shows one line of text per cell, instead of three, in the tableview. It only returns which ever text label is first.

Here is my code for my Class object:

```
class Class: NSObject {
var date_clasname: String?
var teacher: String?
var room_number: String?
init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.date_clasname = dictionary["date_clasname"] as? String ?? ""
    self.teacher = dictionary["teacher"] as? String ?? ""
    self.room_number = dictionary["room_number"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

}

Here is my code for my tableview class:

```
class classes_test_TableViewController: UITableViewController {
let cellId = "cellId"

var users = [Class]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    fetchClass()
}

func fetchClass() {
   // guard let uid = ?.user.uid
       // else{return}
    //let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("Science").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        //print(userID)
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = Class(dictionary: dictionary)
            self.users.append(user)
            print(snapshot)
            //this will crash because of background thread, so lets use dispatch_async to fix
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}

@objc func handleCancel() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // let use a hack for now, we actually need to dequeue our cells for memory efficiency
    //        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    let Class = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = Class.date_clasname
    cell.textLabel?.text = Class.teacher
    cell.textLabel?.text = Class.room_number

    return cell
}

}

class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: 
String?) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

 }
```

Here is my database structure:

```
"Science" : {
"-Lgxm6qJhzI2IIG4uary" : {
  "date_clasname" : "f",
  "room_number" : "d",
  "teacher" : "f"
}
```

The cell is suppose to show all three strings but only shows one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the standard `UITableViewCell` and you assign all three values to the same label.

You have to cast the cell to the custom cell and assign the values to the custom labels

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // let use a hack for now, we actually need to dequeue our cells for memory efficiency
    //        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel?.text = user.date_clasname
    cell.teacherLabel?.text = user.teacher
    cell.roomLabel?.text = user.room_number

    return cell
}
```

Replace `nameLabel`, `teacherLabel` and `roomLabel` with the real property names.

And please conform to the naming convention and name variables *lowerCamelCased* for example `dateClasname` and `roomNumber`